# How to do a queue in order to wait 5 seconds to execute a function

Tags: javascript

I need to put a [debounce](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#debounce) everytime that an object is updated.

Here is the function I need to solve

```
updatePlayerAmount (data) {
    this.state.playerSlots[data.position - 1].playerAmount = data.playerAmount;
  }
```

the param `data` returns something like this

```
{
  playerAmount : 10,
  position     : 2
}
```

the `playerAmount` key will change his value on every click in a certain element.

SO:

everytime the user clicks on certain element, that amount is going to change in the view, but I need that amount to be updated every 5 seconds, it does't matter whether the user clicks 7 times within 2 seconds.

I did it with a `setTimeout` of 5 seconds, but the issue I had, was that the user clicked on the element 7 times within the 5 seconds, and you couldn't see the changes one by one but the full change only once. And I need the user visualizing the changes in the view every 5 seconds.

According to an explanation a coworker gave me, I need to put the new changes in an array, and be listen to those changes... (?) but, how ?

Did you get it ?

PS: I am using `lodash` but I don't how to use it in this case.

**Update**

I did it like this

```
  _playerAmount = (data) => {
    this.state.playerSlots[data.position - 1].playerAmount = data.playerAmount;
  }

  updatePlayerAmount (data) {
    _.debounce(this._playerAmount(data), 5000);
  }
```

but I get an error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function

so, what are your recommendations here ?

Comment: You can use setInterval for calling the update function every 5 seconds. In addition to that you call the update function when the user clicks immediatly as well.

Comment: @user2415266 can I have a code example ?

Comment: Wrote an answer, you have to first clarify what you want, then I can give you code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `.debounce` a *function*.  Right now you are *calling* `this._playerAmount(data)` and passing its return value (`undefined`) to `.debounce`.

Try this:

```
_.debounce(this._playerAmount.bind(this, data), 5000);
```

You can also do:

```
var func = this._playerAmount;
_.debounce(function(){
    func(data);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parts in your question are contraray:

First you say you want to update only every 5 seconds, not when a user clicks.

> everytime the user clicks on certain element, that amount is going to change in the view, but I need that amount to be updated every 5
>   seconds, it does't matter whether the user clicks 7 times within 2
>   seconds.

Then you say the change is only seen after those 5 seconds if he clicked several times.

> I did it with a setTimeout of 5 seconds, but the issue I had, was that
>   the user clicked on the element 7 times within the 5 seconds, and you
>   couldn't see the changes one by one but the full change only once. And
>   I need the user visualizing the changes in the view every 5 seconds.

What exactly do you want? I can help you if you answer me that question.

**Edit:**

**Ok I think I do understand now what you meant by "queueing up the clicks" - this should do it:**

```
function updatePlayerAmount(data) {
    this.state.playerSlots[data.position - 1].playerAmount = data.playerAmount;
}

var clicks = []; // Array to save every new data object in
var notRunning = true; // boolean to determine if there still is a timeout running

function click(data){
    // on each click the data is pushed into the clicks array,
    // then startUpdate() is called
    clicks.push(data);
    startUpdate();
}

function startUpdate(){
    // the worker which makes the timeouts is only called if there
    // is no timeout running still
    if(notRunning){
        notRunning = false;
        worker();       
    }
}

function worker(){
    // if there are no clicks left the worker will stop
    if(clicks.length == 0){
        notRunning = true;
    }else{
        // else it will set a timeout
        window.setTimeOut(function(){
            // updatePlayerAmount is called with the first data in clicks
            updatePlayerAmount(clicks[0]);
            // the first data in clicks gets removed from the array
            clicks.shift();
            // worker calls itself to see if there are still clicks
            worker();
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, once the user clicks on certain element, the counter for 5 seconds should start, the only way to update the view, is with a click on the element I mentioned. What I mean: if the user clicks 7 times in 2 seconds, so every update should be visualized every 5 seconds. One by one.

Comment: and I am using Reactjs, almost pure JavaScript, and lodash, just in case.

Comment: The code I edited should achieve what you were looking for.

Comment: I was unable to adapt this to my code. Look at this answer where I updated the code and the question is a bit more clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289356/updating-component-every-5-seconds-once-socket-is-emitting-an-event