# Updating component every 5 seconds once socket is emitting an event (?)

Tags: javascript

I am working with React and socket.io, every time an event happens there is a socket listening to any changes.

I have this in my actions

```
socket.on('playerCount', (data) => {
  PlayerSlotActions.updatePlayerAmount({
    playerAmount : data.cardCount,
    position     : data.position,
  });
})
```

where the `data` param returns this

```
{
  playerAmount : 10,
  position     : 2
}
```

sometimes from the socket, comes from 4 to 7 events in one shot in order to change the `playerAmount` key to another value. Every time I receive that event, I should change the number of the `playerAmount` to the new number sent from the socket.

My issue:

lets say in the view I have something like `Player Amount: 10`, and then the socket sends the numbers 1, 3 and 5 in one shot, so the new amount would change to 19 which is the sum of the new number, and that is OK, but that change shouldn't happen quick, between the sum of one number and another, there should be 5 seconds of difference, like:

`Player Amount: 10`

*after 5 seconds...*

`Player Amount: 11`

*after 5 seconds...*

`Player Amount: 14`

*after 5 seconds...*

`Player Amount: 19`

... and so on.

so I am trying to figure out which is the best method to use here. With `setTimeout`, it does what I want but only the first attempt, the rest of the sums takes around 1 second of difference even if you put a timeout for 5 seconds.

I am using lodash, so I thought maybe _.debounce, _.throttle or _.delay methods could help, but I was wrong. Only delay works the same way as `setTimeout`

I did it like this

```
socket.on('playerCount', (data) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
   PlayerSlotActions.updatePlayerAmount({
     playerAmount : data.cardCount,
     position     : data.position,
   });
 }, 5000);
});
```

I am just learning this. Is there a way like to store the new numbers in an array or something like this ?

Tell me your recommendations.

---

**Just in case you want to see my code**

the code above is in my `actions`, from the actions, it goes to the `stores`

```
  @bind(PlayerSlotActions.updatePlayerAmount)
  updatePlayerAmount (data) {
    this.state.playerSlots[data.position - 1].playerAmount = data.playerAmount;
  }
```

and from there, it goes directly to the component

```
  componentDidUpdate () {
    let playerAmount = this.props.playerAmount;
    this.refs.playerAmount.getDOMNode().innerHTML = playerAmount;
  }
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
  connect () {

    socket = io.connect('localhost:1101/server');

    socket.on('playerCount', (data) => {
      console.log('1');
      queue.push({
        playerAmount : data.cardCount,
        position     : data.position,
      });
    })

    setTimeout(function() {
      if (queue.length > 0) {
        var data = queue.splice(0, 1)
        PlayerSlotActions.updatePlayerAmount(data);
      }
    }, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: I saw an downvote, before you give an downvote, is fair to say what is wrong with the question, if I am unable to fix it then provide the downvote. So, is there something wrong or are you giving downvotes just because you ignore the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you had problems putting in my code from this question: [How to do a queue in order to wait 5 seconds to execute a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284414/how-to-do-a-queue-in-order-to-wait-5-seconds-to-execute-a-function)

I don't know if you solved it with Will Newton now, but in case you didn't, try this:

```
// variables for the queue and a boolean to
// indicate whether the queue gets worked on or not
var queue = [];
var notRunning = true;

connect () {
    socket = io.connect('localhost:1101/server');

    socket.on('playerCount', (data) => {
      console.log('1');
      queue.push({
        playerAmount : data.cardCount,
        position     : data.position,
      });
      startQueue();
    })

    // Initiating function, has to be seperate because else each socket connect
    // would trigger a new instance of processQueue, which would result
    // in shorter times than 5s between the updates
    function startQueue(){
        if(notRunning){
            notRunning = false;
            processQueue();
        }
    }

    // Recursive function, calls itself every 5 seconds as long as there are
    // items in the queue
    function processQueue(){
        if(queue.length > 0){
            setTimeOut(function(){
                // passes the first item of the queue in your function
                PlayerSlotActions.updatePlayerAmount(queue[0]);
                // removes first item from the queue
                queue.shift();
                processQueue();
            }, 5000)
        }else{
            notRunning = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea about storing data in an array will work.

We can treat the array like a queue.

However, you are limited to it only updating every 5 seconds.

```
var queue = [];

socket.on('playerCount', (data) => {
    queue.push({
       playerAmount : data.cardCount,
       position     : data.position,
    });
});

setInterval(function() {
   if (queue.length > 0) {
     var data = queue.shift();
     PlayerSlotActions.updatePlayerAmount(data);
   }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I am trying to adapt it to my code. Look at my update above please.

Comment: Sure. I can't see where  you define your queue.

Comment: You need to have the queue instantiated before the socket.on() is called

Comment: is defined before the connect (), I didn't pasted, sorry. But I have it defined.

Comment: Oh i have found my mistake. change setTimeout to setInterval

Comment: I am getting an error in the console but I am afraid it has to be with my code in any other pont: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'playerAmount' of undefined`

Comment: Yes that seems unrelated.

Comment: look at the part where I did `Just in case you want to see my code`, that part of my is for the same issue, hay you worked with React ?

Comment: yes, this.state.playerSlots[data.position - 1] is returning undefined

Comment: really ? so what is next step ?

Comment: does your playerSlots array have data in it?

Comment: see what data element it is trying to get: 

`updatePlayerAmount (data) {
   console.log(data.position - 1);
    this.state.playerSlots[data.position - 1].playerAmount = data.playerAmount;
  }`

Comment: tuen console.log(data.position - 1); returns 1

Comment: how about log the following too, in the same spot, just to see what it is returning: `this.state.playerSlots[data.position - 1]`

Comment: the first time it logs `{playerAmount: 0, position: 2, name: "cole", cardCount: 0, currentBet: 4000…}` and the second `{playerAmount: 10, position: 2, name: "cole", cardCount: 0, currentBet: 4000…}`

Comment: and then it throws that exception?

Comment: I was doing those console log without your code, but with your code, the console log returns `undefined` and then the exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'playerAmount' of undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93111/discussion-between-will-newton-and-nietzscheprogrammer).

Comment: @WillNewton setInterval won't achieve that the 5 seconds interval only start when connect recieves data. Instead it will always run. I actually told NietzscheProgrammer yesterday in [his other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284414/how-to-do-a-queue-in-order-to-wait-5-seconds-to-execute-a-function) how he could do it, but apparently he was unable to implement the solution. Checkout my answer below.